# Hibernate Configuration for SQLServer - Driver class

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jdbc, driver

I'm trying to configure hibernate with a SQLServer db.

The configuration:

```
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    try {
        if (null==sessionFactory) {
            Properties hb_props = new Properties();
            hb_props.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect");
            hb_props.put("hibernate.connection.driver.class", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            hb_props.put("hibernate.connection.username", "someusername");
            hb_props.put("hibernate.connection.password", "somepassword");
            hb_props.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:sqlserver://serverurl//dbname");
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.setProperties(hb_props);
            sessionFactory = configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Test.class).buildSessionFactory();
        }
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
[main] WARN org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - no JDBC Driver class was specified by property hibernate.connection.driver_class
[main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using driver: null at URL: jdbc:sqlserver://serverurl//dbname
[main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - connection properties: {user=someusername, password=****, driver.class=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver}
[main] WARN org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://serverurl//dbname
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870)
        .....
```

I'm using sqljdbc-1.2.jar and the driver class seems correctly spelled, cant't figure where is the flaw..

Comment: I assume you have edited the serverurl and database name in the post?

Comment: it will be funny if i doesn't =P,
yes, they've been edited for security purpose, maybe i'm a bit paranoic..

Comment: Thats the right thing to do, I was just making sure it was intentional

Comment: yes it was, and i'm quite sure that the connection string is correct, but now i think that maybe i don't have to put also the database name in the hibernate.connection.url property, if there is a specific property (i'm guessing) for the db name.. going to search

Comment: Found the problem:
I wrote:

    hb_props.put("hibernate.connection.driver.class", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

instead of:

    hb_props.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

Comment: Hehe, I know see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
hb_props.put("hibernate.connection.driver.class",
    "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

To this:

```
hb_props.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class",
   "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

This [configuration guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc) from JBoss uses an `_` instead of a `.`

Comment: That's the answer ;), and I have to say also that the way i declare the property "hibernate.connection.url" it's wrong, instead of "jdbc:sqlserver://serverurl//dbname" the correct string is like: "jdbc:sqlserver://serverurl;databaseName=dbname". In many post I saw that in the hibernate config xml it's written in the first way, i wonder if it's different when it's passed runtime